# How does java implement the conversion of LinkedList to ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, linked-list, big-o

I am implementing a public method that needs a data structure that needs to be able to handle insertion at two ends. Since `ArrayList.add(0,key)` will take **O(N)** time, I decide to use a `LinkedList` instead - the `add` and `addFirst` methods should both take **O(1)** time.

However, in order to work with existing API, my method needs to return an `ArrayList`.
So I have two approaches:

(1) use `LinkedList`,
do all the addition of **N** elements where **N/2** will be added to the front and **N/2** will be added to the end.
Then convert this `LinkedList` to `ArrayList` by calling the `ArrayList` constructor:
`return new ArrayList<key>(myLinkedList);`

(2) use `ArrayList` and call `ArrayList.add(key)` to add **N/2** elements to the back and call `ArrayList.add(0,key)` to add **N/2** elements to the front. Return this `ArrayList`.

Can anyone comment on which option is more optimized in terms of time complexity? I am not sure how Java implements the constructor of `ArrayList` - which is the key factor that decides which option is better.

thanks.

Comment: do you know the value of n when you enter the method?

Comment: The source code is available.. however it's a safe bet that the copy-constructor for `ArrayList` based on a O(N) iterator.

Comment: This is a link to open jdk implementation of ArrayList constructor, http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: @RichardSitze - no, its based on toArray(), which is much faster in ArrayList compared to LinkedList

Comment: @anoopelias Thanks for pointing to the open jdk implementation. For some reason I was not able to find it last night.

Comment: @radai - n is on average in the scale of a few millions (data from a log stream)

Comment: @EricH. - if thats a problem than you should avoid any sort of copy construction and work in-place on the argument youre provided.

Comment: @radai - look at Nirk's response below, which I think makes sense. If I do any work in place - that means I have to plan on the worse case O(N) insertion for N/2 times.  While using a copy construction it may only be a one time cost. Even though that might be NlogN I think it will still be faster than using ArrayList at the beginning.

Comment: @EricH. - time it and see :-)

Comment: You know all those SO questions "why should I use an Interface instead of a Class in my API"?  Linky to this question.  The API that requires an ArrayList is (likely) flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method iterates across the list:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)

> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

which, you can reasonably infer, uses the `iterator` interface.

The second method will shift elements every time you add to the front (and resize every once in a while):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, E)

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

Given the official assumptions regarding the functions, the first method is more efficient.

FYI: you may get more mileage using `LinkedList.toArray`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use an `ArrayDeque` which is faster than a `LinkedList` to insert elements at two ends and consumes less memory. Then convert it to an `ArrayList` using method #1.